# Click button, open Form, close Form and then do something in Parent Form

Tags: c#, forms

I develop an application in Visual Studio using C#.Net with many forms and buttons that open these forms. What I need is to Click a button, open a form that contains data from myDataTable, the user make changes and finally after the form closes the parentFrom doSomethingWith myDataTable. The problem is the program first runs doSomethingWith and then shows the Form. I could call the doSomethingWith from the childForm but the childForm is called several times from several parents forms and it is not convenient. Is there a way to keep this sequence?

```
private void bt_ImportFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     System.Data.DataTable myDatatable = new System.Data.DataTable();
     importForm = new Form_ImportExcel(ref myDatatable);
     importForm.Show();
     doSomethingWith(myDataTable);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to broadcast an event from your child forms and send the data back through the event args which your parent form is listening to.

Comment: You may call it on Form_Closing of child form.

Comment: you should call `ShowDialog` if you want to `doSomethingWith` after the form closes. otherwise it won't wait for the form to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call importForm.ShowDialog() instead. This will block the execution of doSomethingWith(myDataTable) until importForm is closed.

If a form is displayed as modal, the code following the ShowDialog method is not executed until the dialog box is closed. However, when a form is shown as modeless, the code following the Show method is executed immediately after the form is displayed. Refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx) for more details.

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much!